# How do I take high quality screenshots on my iMac?

Tags: macos, screen-capture

I moved my Sims game onto my Mac from Windows. On Windows I had a program called [SRWE](https://github.com/dtgDTGdtg/SRWE)
all bc with  for screenshots where it adjusted the view / zoom of the screen so that when you take screenshots you can get as high quality/res you want.

There is not SRWE on Mac so I'm wondering what way I can get super HQ shots on my Mac.

Comment: I’ve been reading up on what SRWE does and you cannot get “as high quality/res you want”. The app must be running in a window and it must support hot sampling (games, mostly).  The highest resolution you can get is full screen resolution.  macOS’ native screen capture already does this.

Comment: If your Mac has a Retina display, you should find that screen shots are hi-res anyway, using the screen's pixel density. But a lot will depend on how your game looks on-screen.

Answer (score 1):

Cmd-Shift-3 combo puts an image of the entire screen on the clipboard that you can then paste into a graphics program, word processing document, Notes, etc.

Change the 3 to 4 and you can select a section of screen with the mouse.

And on newer Macs, Cmd-Shift-5 gives a more flexible method that can also get a movie of the screen.

Details on Apple’s website:
https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/take-a-screenshot-mh26782/mac